# Conditional reordering of values within column (permutation) in R

Tags: r, permutation

I am working on a research paper on graph manipulation and I have the following data:

```
              returns 1+returns  cum_return   price         period_ret(step=25)
    1    7.804919e-03 1.0078049  0.007804919 100.78355           NA
    2    3.560800e-03 1.0035608  0.011393511 101.14306           NA
    3   -1.490719e-03 0.9985093  0.009885807 100.99239           NA
    .   -2.943304e-03 0.9970567  0.006913406 100.69558           NA
    .    1.153007e-03 1.0011530  0.008074385 100.81175           NA
    .   -2.823012e-03 0.9971770  0.005228578 100.52756           NA
   25   -7.110762e-03 0.9928892 -0.001919363  99.81526        -0.02364
    .   -1.807268e-02 0.9819273 -0.019957356  98.02754           NA
    .   -3.300315e-03 0.9966997 -0.023191805  97.70455           NA
   250   5.846750e-03 1.0058467 -0.017480652  98.27748         0.12125
```

These are 250 daily stock returns, the cummulative return, price and the 25-day period returns (returns between days 0-25; 25-50;...;200-250).

What I want to do is the following:

I want to rearrange the returns but the period returns should be identical although their order can change. So there are 10! possible combinations of the subsets.

What I did so far: I wrote a code using the `sample`, `repeat` and `identical` functions and here is a shortened version:

```
repeat{
temp <- tibble(
       returns = sample(x$returns, 250, replace=TRUE) )

if(identical(sort(round(c(x$period_ret[(!is.na(x$period_ret))]),2)),sort(round(c(temp$period_ret[(!is.na(temp$period_ret))]),2)))) break
}
```

This took me quite some time and unfortunately it isn't of any real use. Only later I began thinking of the math and that there are 250! possible samples so I would spend days waiting for any result.

What do I need this for?

I would like to create graphs with different orders of the returns. Thus, all the graphs have the same summary statistics but look different. Its important that they have the same period_returns (no matter of their order) to fulfil a utility formula.

Comment: Think of a the following list: 1 2 3. There 3! (=3x2x1) = 6 possible permuations or different orders of how you write them down. So for 250 elements there should be 250! orders if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, I am permuting the elements of colum returns. This column has 250 different elements.